# Track onDisconnect on multi-subscription nestjs server

Tags: graphql, nestjs, apollo, react-apollo, subscription

So I've got NestJs application, where I've gotmultiple subscriptions. from client side on my react app with apolloClinet I'm listening one continuously that's notification Listener.

I also have messaging subscription that fetches new messages when I'm in chat. I want my setup to be set like when user open chatRoom to add in listeners in db, and when he leaves fetchNewMessages subscription to delete from chatRoom Listeners

so I did this on my subscription resolver that is adding currentUser in chatRoom Listener list

```js
     fetchNewMessage(@CurrentUser('') user: User, @Args('chatRoomId') chatRoomId: string) {
    this.messagesService.addRemoveListenerOnChatRoom(chatRoomId, user.id, 'add')
    return PubSub.asyncIterator('newMessage')
    }
```

but when I'm leaving chatRoom I don't have access onDisconnect property to remove them from listeners

I only have main application graphql-ws onDisconnect method on app

```js
subscriptions: {
        'graphql-ws': {
          onConnect: context => {
            const { connectionParams, extra } = context
            const authToken = connectionParams.Authorization && connectionParams.Authorization.replace('Bearer ', '')
            const user = authService.getJwtPayLoad(authToken)
            // when using with graphql-ws, additional context value should be stored in the extra field
            extra.headers = { user, authorization: connectionParams.Authorization }
          },
          onDisconnect: (websocket, context) => {
            const user = context.extra.user
            user && messagesService.addRemoveListenerOnChatRoom(null, user.id, 'remove')
          },
        },
        context: ({ extra }) => {
          return extra
          // you can now access your additional context value through the extra field
        },
```

but this isn't useful cause I'm always listening to notification subscription so if I leave fetchNewChatRoom listener this onDisconnect will not work

so is there any suggest or best practices on multi subscription servers ? can I adjust properties on individual subscription onDisconnect ?